# TreeViewAdv: How to add columns and nodes in Vb .Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, treeview

Anyone using [TreeViewAdv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/treeviewadv/) ?

On Internet, there is NO information about how to use it in VB .Net.

Can someone explain that how to add nodes and columns in it, in VB .Net please?

Comment: `On Internet, there is NO information about how to use it in VB .Net. Can someone explain that how to add nodes and columns in it, in VB .Net` sorry we are not a code service. Also there are many examples out there that do it...

Comment: Not in Vb .Net, but C#, C++... I see many question like "code service" here, but I can't argue that. Although you are right, maybe someone can help me,

Comment: Interesting as I just navigated to that code and it has all the code there... in **vb.net and c#**

Comment: Interesting... So you can answer the question in short way?